# Core plot - gradient below line

Tags: ios, core-plot

I've been trying to setup the gradient under the plot:

```
//add gradient to line
    CPTColor *underLineGradientStartColor       = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:CPTFloat(0.0) green:CPTFloat(1.0) blue:CPTFloat(0.0) alpha:CPTFloat(1.0)];
    CPTColor *underLineGradientEndColor         = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:CPTFloat(1.0) green:CPTFloat(0.0) blue:CPTFloat(0.0) alpha:CPTFloat(1.0)];
    CPTGradient *underLineGradient              = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:underLineGradientStartColor endingColor:underLineGradientEndColor];
    underLineGradient.angle                     = -90.0;
    CPTFill *underLineGradientFill              = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:underLineGradient];
    dataSourceLinePlot.areaFill                 = underLineGradientFill;
```

I've also set up the areaBaseValues:

```
dataSourceLinePlot.areaBaseValue = @0;
dataSourceLinePlot.areaBaseValue2 = @255;
```

The values I am going to plot are in the range 0-255 (range of plot is set to be constant). Sometimes, however, I receive invalid values (e.g. 1000). Incorrect values are not shown as they are out of range. The gradients, however, want to fill them and in the result the gradient is not visible (only the lowest part of it is on the screen - not full range). How can I change it?

EDIT:
This is how it looks now:
[image]
I want to have gradient from 0 to 255 (values above 255 can be solid green).

Comment: Do you want the fill to appear under the invalid values or do you want a gap in the fill?

Comment: The invalid values now appear, but they are cut at 255 (max range- it is correct). I want to have gradient max at 255 and all values above in for example solid green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the datasource clip the invalid data points to a value that is just outside the maximum value of the plot range. For example, if the plot range will never go above 255, have the datasource return a y-value of 255.1 for any invalid data point. It doesn't matter what the fill above 255 is since it's outside the plot area and you'll never see it.

Comment: This is what I already did to overcome this problem. I thought that baseValues where meant to do that in CorePlot. Thanks for the help.